# Get current cell text from a DataGridView, but when an DataError is caught

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Context: WinForms and C#

I'm trying to show a `MessageBox` with the text that user is trying to enter, like for example, if the column is an integer type column, he gets a `MessageBox` saying:

> The value "Abcdef" you entered doesn't match with this column type

I know how to get the column type, but how can I get that text?

```
private void dgv_Datos_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("The value you tried (" + dgv_Datos.CurrentCell.Value.ToString() + ") doesn't match with this column type");
}
```

The thing is that `CurrentCell.Value.ToString()` only works if the previous text was right. If it was a Byte column and you entered 100, and then changed to "Abcdef", you get "100" in the messagebox error.

Thanks!

Comment: ([CellValidating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating) + `e.FormattedValue` + [RefreshEdit()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.refreshedit)) + [ShowCellErrors = true](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.showcellerrors)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void dgv_Datos_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("The value you tried (" + dgv_Datos.EditingControl.Text + ") doesn't match with this column type");
}
```